# Unable to take screenshots from android emulator using calabash

Tags: calabash-android

android` for my UIAutomation testing. I encounter the following in the console. Any suggestion?

```
Success
  Background:                # features/02_login/login.feature:4
    Given the app is running # features/android/step_definitions/common_actions.rb:8
Could not take screenshot
java.io.IOException: EOF
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:643)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296)
    at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source)
    at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source)
    at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer to it. Use `SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB=false`